# Calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k^2}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

> Calculate the sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k^2}$$

I'm supposed to calculate it without using functions like Gamma, Zeta, Digamma, etc...

What I tried:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+i)(k-i)}=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\bigg( \frac{1}{k-i} - \frac{1}{k+i}\bigg)$$

Comment: You definitely want just the first $n$ terms, not the $n\to\infty$ limit?

Comment: Yes, the $n$ term. The limit is easier (but not simple).

Comment: I can imagine expressing it as an integral, by finding a function with the right residues.  Would that be legitimate?

Comment: Well, rewriting in terms of Digamma Functions [is possible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5En+1%2F%28k%5E2%2B1%29), but neither wanted nor really insightful.

Comment: @MathBuster Since you are looking for closed form, please let me know if my answer is not useful I can delete suddenly. Thanks

Comment: The exact value is required not an approximation.

Comment: For the denominator, see [OEIS A193181](https://oeis.org/A193181). There is no cited formula, so I might guess no "basic" closed form expression is known for this.

Comment: @MathBuster: There are brackets missing around the terms at the right-most sum.

Answer (score 3):

The partial sums of $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+1}$ have no simple closed form other than $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+k^2}$. On the other hand the value of the series can be computed in a rather elementary way. We may consider that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$
$$ \frac{1}{k^2+1} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}e^{-x}\,dx $$
holds by integration by parts. Since 
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k} $$
is the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function $w(x)$ which equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on $(0,2\pi)$, we have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+1} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}w(x)e^{-x}\,dx = \sum_{m\geq 0}\int_{2m\pi}^{2(m+1)\pi}w(x)e^{-x}\,dx =\sum_{m\geq 0}e^{-2m\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}e^{-x}\,dx.$$
By computing the very last integral it follows that
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+1} = \left[\frac{\pi-1}{2}+\frac{\pi+1}{2}e^{-2\pi}\right]\sum_{m\geq 0}e^{-2m\pi}= \left[\frac{\pi-1}{2}+\frac{\pi+1}{2}e^{-2\pi}\right]\frac{e^{2\pi}}{e^{2\pi}-1}$$
or
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2+1} = \left[\pi\cosh(\pi)-\sinh(\pi)\right]\frac{1}{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\coth(\pi)-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over 1 + k^{2}} & =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + \ic}\pars{k - \ic}} =
-\,{1 \over 2\ic}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{{1 \over k + \ic} -
{1 \over k - \ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 + \ic} =
-\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k + 1 + \ic} -
{1 \over k + n + 1 + \ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\Im\Psi\pars{n + 1 + \ic} + \Im\Psi\pars{1 + \ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffc,border:1px solid navy]{-\Im\Psi\pars{n + 1 + \ic} - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\pi\coth\pars{\pi}}
\end{align}

$\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_258.htm). See $\color{black}{\bf 6.3.13}$ and $\color{black}{\bf 6.3.16}$
[in this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).